# HTML currency input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am attempting to create an input field that is used to enter currency. This is for a mobile app built using Ionic. I want the input field to only show the number pad when clicked. However, I would like for the field to show as currency. So when the user first clicks the field, the number pad would show and the input field would show as $0.00. Then as the user entered numbers, the field would look like this:

```
User enters 1 : $0.01
User enters 5 : $0.15
User enters 2 : $1.52
```

and so on.

Comment: Have you tried something you can show? This may serve you: http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/

Comment: That library seems to be working great. Thanks @ItaloAyres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I could find for this was the library suggested in the comments.

http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/

Answer (score 1):

The usual way in angular is to use a filter in an expression. So if you have a $scope.myvalue variable:

```
<div class='whatever'>{{ myvalue | currency }}</div>
```